# Laravel website upload on cPanel error

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, cpanel

I have been trying to upload the Laravel website on a shared hosting .in the cPanel, file manager root directory I made a folder called Laravel and kept all the files except public files which I have kept in the `public_html`. I changed my index.php to `../laravel/bootstrap` now as far as I know it should be showing a SQL error but it not. It is showing me a blank white page.

When I click on the source code there is no source code. It is totally empty like it is not able to access the views of my Laravel folder and in error logs the error is:

> '/ [Tue Mar 21 15:56:28.259166 2017] [core:crit] [pid 19184] (13)Permission denied: [client 182.64.66.54:54866] AH00529: /home/tncpscouriers/public_html/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/home/tncpscouriers/public_html/' is executable, referer: http://tncpscouriers.com"

I have made sure about the PHP version, which is 5.6 and I have double checked the permissions. I have no idea about what the content of .htaccess file should be but this is my .htaccess file:

```
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

```

Comment: Put your whole laravel directory structure inside public_html/someFolder 
(someFolder if you need) and then try to run and let me know if you are facing any problem.

Comment: okay so made a new folder called laravel put all the content inside it and moved it into public_html .i didn't changed the index.php which is ../laravel/bootstrap and it still shows me a blank page i also tried removing the two dots and changing the path to /laravel/bootstrap/ and it still shows a blank page

Comment: Okay now try to run this folder site-url/laravel, or site-url/laravel/public.

Comment: @rahul chauhan when i do site-url/laravel it lists all the files that are in laravel folder.in the format index of /laravel folder and then all the files with name last modified and description.

Comment: wait I will give you .htaccess file for that and put it into root directory.
like
inside public_html/laravel/.htaccess

Comment: thanks.just to let you know,inside the laravel folder there is no public files public files are all lying with laravel folder inside public_html.

Comment: Please get into the habit of using paragraphs - the wall of text before I edited is was difficult to read.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

If your application is built in php version 7 then use this .htaccess file.

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php70 .php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

for rest of the php version<7, use this .htaccess file.

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .php .php5 .php4 .php3 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: just to double check this should be added inside the public_html/laravel folder right along with all the files and not in the public_html, along with public files

Comment: is your website running on sub-domain ?

Comment: Is your website successfully running on site-url/laravel ?

Comment: now it gives a 500 server error on sites-url/laravel and blank page on site -url .and the error in the logs is still the same

Comment: sure it is readable and that '/home/tncpscouriers/public_html/' is executable
[Tue Mar 21 15:07:12.381284 2017] [core:crit] [pid 6867] (13)Permission denied: [client 66.249.79.130:49898] AH00529: /home/tncpscouriers/public_html/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/home/tncpscouriers/public_html/' is executable

Comment: no the site is not running on subdomain.initially it was showing the directory structure of all the files inside the folder.nowit is showing internal 500 error.

Comment: Change from:

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

to:

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ laravel/public/$1 [L]

Comment: still the same error.internal 500 error. and same error in error logs.

Comment: and my website works perfectly fine on local server i double checked it.

Comment: Some of the last solutions

1) Make sure index.php within /public_html has 644 permissions (mine was 664 and that was the cause of the Internal Server Error).

2) Try once put your webisite directly into root public_html directory and put .htaccess provided by me because it works for me.

now, Hope this suggestion will help you.

Comment: i tried everything and i still shows a 500 internal error and the error log still shows the same error that it is not readable when clearly the permission is 644.oh man i am so done

Comment: i tried changing the permissions of.htaccess to 744 and now it shows this error,[Wed Mar 22 01:54:10.712962 2017] [core:alert] [pid 20951] [client 117.224.70.195:47014] /home/tncpscouriers/public_html/.htaccess: </IfModule> without matching <IfModule> section.does that help??

Comment: now i changed my .htacces to your.htaccess file and it is showing me this error "RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters" @Rahul

Comment: I think this is perfect. 
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .php .php5 .php4 .php3 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

but I don't know why are you getting this error. google it out definitely you will get solutions today itself. good luck!

Comment: bro,i actually deleted everything and tried uploading a simple new project wih nothing new just default laravel website that we can generate through terminal and and i uploaded all the folders in the public_html ,made changes in env file from local host to site-url and it still does not work..still shows me a white blank page.does that mean the problem is with the hosting website ot something.because atleast a basic website should get uploaded.

Comment: There are some reason while we get blank page.

1) If your storage and bootstrap/cache folder don't have 777 permission.
2) PHP version issue. 

Check these two things and let me know.